# non relative clause with "in that"

Tags: sentence-structure, expression

I could not find a proper title for my question,this usage shows where the similarity or difference are in comparing facts.

How could I translate **in that** part in following sentence.

> En: Second language acquisition is similar to the first language acquisition in that they have the same stages of development.
>
> De:Zweitspracherwerb ist ähnlich der ersten Spracherwerb, in dem der die gleichen Phasen der Entwicklung haben.

Comment: What about a simple "because"? _Der Zweitspracherwerb ist ähnlich dem Erstspracherwerb, **weil** (because) sie die gleichen Entwicklungsphasen haben._ (I replaced "Phasen der Entwicklung" with "Entwicklungsphasen". "Entwicklungsstufen" would fit as well or even better.)

Comment: I would rather use "insofern als," as I think "because" has a different connotation. "Because" implies causality, while "in that" points to the aspect in which the two processes are similar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I marked a possible translation of "in that".

> De: Der Zweitsprachenerwerb ist **insofern** genauso wichtig wie der
>   Erstspracherwerb, **als** dass sie die gleichen Phasen der Entwicklung
>   haben.

Notice that "in that" is divided in two parts ("insofern" and "als")